# Simplify the following expression. Cite a property from for every step.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Simplify the following expression. $((A ∩ (B ∪ C)) ∩ (A − B)) ∩ (B ∪ C^c )$

$((A ∩ ( B ∪ C ) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)$ By set difference

$(A ∩ B) ∪ ( A ∩ C ) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)$ By distribution law

$(A ∩ B) ∪ ( A ∩ B^c ) ∩ (A ∩ C) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)$ By commutative law

$(A ∩ ( B ∩ B^c ) ∩ (A ∩ C) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)$ By complement law

$(A ∩ U) ∩ (A ∩ C) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)$ By idempotent law

$A ∩ (A ∩ C) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)$ by identity law

I'm not sure i'm doing this right. Assistants would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this your homework. Please show your efforts

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 steps are right. From the 3rd, let
$$
I=((A ∩ B) ∪ ( A ∩ C )) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)
$$
\begin{align}
I&=((A ∩ B) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c))\cup (( A ∩  C) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c))
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by distribution law)}
\\
&=((A ∩ A) ∩ (B ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c))\cup (( A ∩  C) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c))
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by commutative and associative law)}
\\
&=((A ∩ A) ∩ \varnothing ∩ (B ∪ C^c))\cup (( A ∩  C) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c))
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by complement law)}
\\
&=\varnothing \cup (( A ∩  C) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c))
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by identity law)} 
\\
&=( A ∩  C) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∪ C^c)
\\&\quad\quad\text{by }X\cup \varnothing =X
\\
&=((A ∩  C) ∩ (A ∩ B^c) ∩ B)\cup ((A ∩ C) ∩(A ∩ B^c) ∩ C^c)
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by distribution law)}
\\
&=((A ∩  C) ∩ A ∩ (B^c ∩ B))\cup ((C ∩ C^c) ∩(A ∩ B^c) ∩ A)
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by commutative and associative law)}
\\
&=((A ∩  C) ∩ A ∩ \varnothing )\cup (\varnothing  ∩(A ∩ B^c) ∩ A)
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by complement law)}
\\
&=\varnothing \cup \varnothing =\varnothing 
\\&\quad\quad\text{(by idempotent and identity law) } 
\end{align}

Comment: The error in Mac's work was the invalid $(X\cup Y)\cap Z=(X\cup Z)\cap Y$ where $X=A\cap B$ and $Y=A\cap C$ and $Z=A\cap B^c$.

Comment: Thank you. I somewhat understand. I'm really bad at these. I do try to practice a lot. Any pointers/recommendation.